Cannot remove a post from saves from the Q&A page
Steps to reproduce:

Visit any question. Hint: you are currently looking at one.
Add it to your Saves by clicking the icon under the post score.
Refresh the page.
Click the same icon again.

Expected: The icon loses its fill colour and the post is no longer in your saves. 
Actual: A banner on the top saying "An error occurred" and the post remains in Saves.
This only applies on Q&A pages. Same for both a question and any answer. You can still go to your Saves page in your profile and remove the post from there. Also works if you save and unsave without a reload.
The network call has one of the worse error descriptions possible:

{"ErrorMessage":"isUndo parameter is misaligned with post's save status."}

Which is strongly reminiscent of PC LOAD LETTER in that the words have meaning but reading them together barely explains what happens unless you also know the secret meanings of the words and how the system works.
So, to translate the error message for the wider audience, it means "You are trying to save a post which is already saved". Hint: try to word your error messages to not require a graduate-level expert in SE arcana and web development experience to understand.
Here is why that message shows: to save a post, the following request is sent:
POST /<post id>/save

CORRECT to remove a save, the correct request is:
POST /<post id>/save?isUndo=true

INCORRECT right now, the problem is that when the request sent when trying to remove a save is:
POST /<post id>/save

Yes, exactly the same as when saving a post. Presumably, if the isUndo parameter is missing, it is defaulted to false therefore the message complaining about the missing isUndo parameter not matching the state of the post is trying to say "isUndo is false but this is not expected". Which in even planer terms is because saving a saved post.
